# Как разрешить именовать свойства в camelCase в классах миксинах используя пакет @typescript-eslint

Tags: vue.js, typescript, eslint

Для написания frontend используем **Vue** + **TS** и **ESLint**. Для соблюдения **code style** используем плагин **@typescript-eslint**.

Проблема заключается в том, пропсы пишутся в `camelCase` и при **class style** написании компонентов, они являются свойствами класса. А свойства в проекте принято писать в `snake_case`. Для файлов компонентов мы переопределили эти правила, но миксины имеют расширение `.ts`, а соответственно попадают под правила, не предназначенные для компонентов(`.vue`).

Возможно ли как-то решить эту проблему не добавляя использования `camelCase` в файлах `.ts`, что в дальнейшем потребует устного согласования именования свойств класса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хороший вариант предложили в [issue](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/3614). Мне вариант очень понравился.

Идея заключается в том, чтобы именовать файлы с подрасширением(поправьте в комментарии если я не верно назвал нижеследующее) и в таком случае мы можем писать проще правила под файлы.

Пример:

Для классов-примесей используем расширение `.mixin.ts`.

```js
files: ['*.mixin.ts'],
rules: {
  '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': [
    'error',
    {
      selector: 'classProperty',
      format: ['snake_case', 'camelCase'],
    },
  ],
},
```